# Setup individual sizes for different images from .css

Tags: html, css

I know it is very basic, but I'm trying to figure out, how to give different sizes for different images from `.css` to `.html` if I have many images to setup sizes from `.css`.

If I have size for one image `myimg1.png`:

```
<img src="assets/image/myimg1.png"/>
```

in `.css`:

```
img{
  width: 212px;
  height: 95px;
}
```

then I'm not able to give different size for another one `myimg2.png` directly:

```
<img src="assets/image/myimg2.png" width="65" height="72" />
```

Guide or example would be useful

Comment: If you specify the width and height in an inline style attribute like this `<img src="assets/image/myimg2.png" style="width: 65px; height: 72px;" /> `, that should work for it would override the stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using CSS selectors the right way.

```css
img {

}
```

Means you will apply the style to all `<img>` HTML tags.

To differentiate between different `<img>` tags, you need to use CSS classes:

```html
<img src="assets/image/myimg1.png" class="imgOne" />
<img src="assets/image/myimg2.png" class="imgTwo" />
```

```css
.imgOne {
  width: 212px;
  height: 95px;
}

.imgTwo {
  width: 65px;
  height: 72px;
}
```

In your example, the HTML element's attributes `width` and `height` are overridden by the CSS `img` selector.

You can avoid this by either using the CSS as mentioned above, or by changing your HTML to:

```html
<img src="assets/image/myimg2.png" style="width: 65px; height: 72px;" />
```

The content of the `style` attribute is basically CSS, and will take precedence over what's defined inside your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style different images differently and if you do not want to use class for every images then you can make use of `:nth-of-type()` selector like this:

```css
/* Select first img element */
img:nth-of-type(1) {
...
}

/* Select nth img element */
img:nth-of-type(n) {
...
}

/* Select even positioned img elements */
img:nth-of-type(even) {
...
}

/* Select odd positioned img element */
img:nth-of-type(odd) {
...
}
```

For more explanation, please refer:
1. [CSS Tricks - nth-of-type()](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)
2. [CSS3 structural pseudo-class selector tester](http://lea.verou.me/demos/nth.html)